# How to find out the data that in a list that min and the max of that series are less than 100?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that I need to find the values that are less that 100 in total for example the list below:

```
[855, 905, 945, 1405, 1445]
```

when you subtract the max and min in the list of '855', '905', '945', the difference are less than 100. So I want to have a output like :

```
[855, 905, 945]
```

or if I have below list:

```
[855, 905, 915, 945, 1405, 1445]
```

The output should be:

```
[855, 905, 915, 945]
```

Another example is:

```
[800,955,1030,1045,1445,1455]
```

and the output should be:

```
[955,1030,1045]
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: To be clear, the input values will be sorted ahead of time? And you want to go through a step at a time and make groups of the values, based on when the value exceeds a certain threshold (the beginning value in the group, plus the group size of 100)? Well - what happened *when you tried to write code for this yourself*, following those logical steps? Also, why are the values strings rather than integers?

Comment: Can you please put an explanation of how max-min difference you got less than 100?
For the first input, max is 1445 and min 855. So, how you define and expect then out `['855', '905', '945']`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for your comment. The list can be converted to integer so we can assume they are integers rather than string. And yes, They are pre sorted. so it is not necessarily from the beginning. The condition can happen at the end or middle of the list. I will add another example to the question asap

Comment: @mhhabib thanks for your comment. I mean the selected string like ['855', '905', '945'] should have a min and max that the difference are less than 100

Comment: Okay, so *what happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem*? What specific part of it did you find yourself unable to do?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I also changed the string to int in question. So this part is a small ending part of my project that cannot figure it out. The project is related to retrieving data from CSV file that has name of employee and their meeting timestamp. I could do all except this last part

Comment: Okay, and *what happened when you tried to write code to solve this part*? Can you at least explain the algorithm needed to solve it? If so, what step of it do you find difficult?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I cannot think of any algorithm that does this, but I think we should have to start from the first indices and then compare it with the next indices. then keep doing this until two condition satisfies . 1) we find at least three timestamp (numbers) and also that at least 3 or more numbers' max and min's difference are less than 100.

Comment: Right; that's the algorithm. Now you should *try to write code that follows those steps* and see where, specifically, you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

0. First you need to convert all strings in your list to integers
1. You need to find min or max value in the list using min() or max() function on your list
2. So if all the numbers in the list or up to 100 more than min value or 100 less than max value.
3. Apply lambda on your list to filter all numbers with in the range

   ```
    l =  ['855', '905', '945', '1405', '1445']   
    l = [int(i) for i in l]
    min_number = min(l)
    max_target = min_number + 100
    max_number = max(l)
    min_target = max_number - 100

    final_list_min = list(filter(lambda num: num<max_target, l))
    final_list_max = list(filter(lambda num: num>min_target, l))
    if len(final_list_min) < len(final_list_max):
        print (final_list_max)
    else:
        print (final_list_min)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this won't work for such examples: ['800','955','1030','1045','1445','1455']

Comment: So basically you want to find sub set of a list with maximum number of elements from the input list whose min and max can differ by up to 100, In this case min or max value need not be same as the min or max of original list, is that correct?

Comment: so the min and the max of list that we want to extract should be less than 100. for example 1401, 1431, 1446 is the answer for [901, 931, 1401, 1431, 1446]

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet will help you get the desired result.

```
def max_min_100(a):
    try:
        a =  list(map(int, a)) # Convert a elements of list into integers
    except ValueError as e:# raise error if there is a non integer element in the list
        print(e) 
        return None
    
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if max(a)-min(a) < 100:
            return a 
        else:
            a.pop() # pop() removes and returns last object or obj from the list.
    return None


a = ['855', '905', '915', '945', '1405', '1445']
print(max_min_100(a)) # output : [855, 905, 915, 945]
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not work on [901, 931, 1401, 1431, 1446]. the result should be [1401, 1431, 1446].

Comment: [901, 931, 1401, 1431, 1446] can have multiple sub-lists which satisfy the required constraint. The output of the above code is  [901, 931] which is not wrong. Please specify any additional constraints which makes the desired output as [1401, 1431, 1446].

Comment: Thanks, I will try but we had the same issue in another answer and I could not figure it out, Thanks btw